# how to set width and height of html-page inside <iframe srcDoc={htmlPage}>

Tags: html, css, reactjs, iframe, html-email

I want to preview the HTML content (which comes from the backend as a string) in my react application. I'm setting the iframe `srcDoc` as shown below.

`<iframe width="100%" height="515px" srcDoc={previewTemplate}></iframe>`

the width and height properties are setting the dimensions of the iframe. How to set the width and height of HTML content inside?

NOTE: HTML page is responsive
HTML page used can be viewed [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ayurdhata/xmLkh6ap/4/)

Comment: Iframes dont work in `html-email`. It will work when you preview emails in browser but it will not work in email clients.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the code below with peace of mind.

```
<iframe srcDoc={previewTemplate} onload="this.width=screen.width;this.height=screen.height;">
```

Comment: Iframe's don't work on emails.